# Problem With Sqlite3 Database Using Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have been trying to figure out my logic. I perform the following to open my database:

```swift
func createDB() -> OpaquePointer?{
        
    var db : OpaquePointer?
    
    guard sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK else {
        print("error opening database")
        sqlite3_close(db)
        db = nil
        return nil
    }
    
    return db
}
```

I then try to perform the following `select` statement:

```swift
let queryString = "select photo_id from unsplash_photos"
        
var statement: OpaquePointer?

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &statement, nil)) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")
}

var rc = sqlite3_step(statement)

while rc == SQLITE_ROW {
    print("row",rc)
    
    rc = sqlite3_step(statement)
}
```

When this runs the result is printing 100 for every step.

```
row 100
row 100
row 100
row 100
row 100
row 100
row 100
row 100
row 100
```

Does this have something to do with how the database is setup? Does this have to do with how the tables are situated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is telling you that it found 9 rows of data, returning `SQLITE_ROW` (`100`) each time. If you want to do extract the data, you have to call [`sqlite3_column_xxx()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) to get the data for the respective row. E.g., `sqlite3_column_int` if the `photo_id` is an integer:

```swift
let queryString = "select photo_id from unsplash_photos"

var statement: OpaquePointer?

guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryString, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")
    return
}

var rc = sqlite3_step(statement)

// as long as there's a row of data returned, display it

while rc == SQLITE_ROW {
    let id = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)
    print("id =", id)

    rc = sqlite3_step(statement)
}

// at the end, we should have gotten `SQLITE_DONE`, and if not, show the error

if rc != SQLITE_DONE {
    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
    print("rc =", rc, "error = ", errmsg)
}

// clean up when we're done

sqlite3_finalize(statement)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SQLITE_ROW` is a condition code whose value is 100.  It means "sqlite3_step() has another row ready" according to [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).  It it is not the number of the row returned.